# Conversion operator with ref-qualifers: rvalue ref and const lvalue ref overloads ambiguity

Tags: c++, conversion-operator, ref-qualifier

While answering [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74187665/user-defined-operator-conversion-resolution-order), I noticed something peculiar about conversion operators when dealing with ref-qualifiers.

Consider the following code:

```
using P = std::unique_ptr<int>;

struct A {
    P p;
    operator P() && { return std::move(p); }
    operator P const&() const& { return p; }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    P p;
    p = std::move(a);
}
```

This does not compile because apparently there is ambiguity when selecting the correct operator overload (see the errors in the demo below). It works if I remove the `const` qualifier on the second overload like this:

```
operator P const&() & { return p; }
```

Also, if instead of an assignment I simply construct a `P` object, it also works:

```
P p = std::move(a);
```

However, this only happens for conversion operators. If instead I write a normal member function that does the exact same thing, it compiles just fine.

```
struct B {
    P p;
    P get() && { return std::move(p); }
    P const& get() const& { return p; }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    P p;
    p = std::move(b).get();
}
```

Why is that? What's so special about a conversion operator for these overloads to be ambiguous when they aren't on a normal member function?

[Full demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zT1vWPjqo)

Side note: if instead of `std::unique_ptr<int>`, I use a custom non-copyable type, nothing changes.

```
struct P {
    P() = default;
    P(P const&) = delete;
    P(P&&) = default;
    P& operator=(P const&) = delete;
    P& operator=(P&&) = default;
};
```

Other side note: for some reason, MSVC doesn't say there is an ambiguity, it just selects the wrong overload. Unless I use my custom non-copyable type, in which case it agrees the call is ambiguous. So I guess it has to do with `std::unique_ptr::operator=`. Not too important, but if you have any idea why, I'd love to know.

Comment: FWIW copy construction works, but assignment doesn't: https://godbolt.org/z/9n441MrEc

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade Good point, I noticed it but forgot to put it in the question.

Comment: I would look into the `std::unique_ptr::operator=`.

Comment: Ref qualifiers. Holy <expletive deleted> I can never remember those dang things. Every time I look at code like that, the WTF?!? alarm goes off.

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade I tried with a custom non-copyable type, nothing changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `p = std::move(a)`, it is actually `p.operator=(std::move(a))`. There are two relevant candidates for this function:

```cpp
P& operator=(P&&) noexcept;  // (1) Move assign operator
P& operator=(const P&);      // (2) Copy assign operator
```

The fact that the second one is deleted isn't considered yet.

So, the conversion from a `A` rvalue to something that `P&&` would accept in (1) calls the user defined conversion function `operator P() &&`.

For the second overload, it would call `operator const P&() const&`.

Both of these options are user-defined conversion functions, so neither is better in terms of overload resolution, thus an ambiguity.

But if you remove the `const` from `operator const P&() /*const*/&`, it can no longer be called (since `std::move(a)` isn't an lvalue, so it can't call an lvalue qualified function if they aren't const qualified), and there is no ambiguity since the other choice is removed.

You can try it yourself for a function not named `operator=`:

```
struct P {
    void f(const P&) = delete;
    void f(P&&) {}
};

struct A {
    P p;
    operator P() && { return std::move(p); }
    operator P const&() const& { return p; }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    P p;
    p.f(std::move(a));
}
```

---

For the case of `B`, `std::move(b).get()` is either going to be of type `P` or `const P`. The overload resolution is done by the call to `get()`, and an rvalue ref qualified function wins over a const lvalue ref qualified function for an rvalue, `std::move(b).get()` is going to be an rvalue `P`, and there are no ambiguities in choosing the move assign operator.

---

For `P p = std::move(a);`, the overload resolution is a bit different: Since it is initializing a `P` object, it's looking for the best way to convert from `std::move(a)`.
The candidates are all the constructors of `P` + all the conversion functions of `a`.
`operator P() &&` beats `operator P() const&` because the conversion being considered is from `std::move(a)` to `A&&` or `const A&` to call the conversion operator, not to `P&&` or `const P&` when matching arguments of a constructor.

Comment: Do you mind 'splaining why does `P p = std::move(a);` work?

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade overload resolution is confusing, but hopefully the explanation I've added makes sense

Comment: Thanks @Artyer. I sort of get it... but it's too late for me and I've got my mind on other things. Anyway, συν ένα for the general explanation.